# How do I use the relationships between Flann matches to determine a sensible homography?

Tags: image, opencv, homography, flann, flannbasedmatcher

I have a panorama image, and a smaller image of buildings seen within that panorama image. What I want to do is recognise if the buildings in that smaller image are in that panorama image, and how the 2 images line up.

For this first example, I'm using a cropped version of my panorama image, so the pixels are identical.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import math

# Load images
cwImage = cv2.imread('cw1.jpg',0)
panImage = cv2.imread('pan1.jpg',0)

# Prepare for SURF image analysis
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(4000)

# Find keypoints and point descriptors for both images
cwKeypoints, cwDescriptors = surf.detectAndCompute(cwImage, None)
panKeypoints, panDescriptors = surf.detectAndCompute(panImage, None)
```

[image]

[image]

Then I use OpenCV's FlannBasedMatcher to find good matches between the two images:

```
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

# Find matches between the descriptors
matches = flann.knnMatch(cwDescriptors, panDescriptors, k=2)

good = []

for m, n in matches:
  if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
    good.append(m)
```

[image]

So you can see that in this example, it perfectly matches the points between images. So then I find the homography, and apply a perspective warp:

```
cwPoints = np.float32([cwKeypoints[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good
                          ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
panPoints = np.float32([panKeypoints[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good
                          ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
h, status = cv2.findHomography(cwPoints, panPoints)

warpImage = cv2.warpPerspective(cwImage, h, (panImage.shape[1], panImage.shape[0]))
```

[image]

Result is that it perfectly places the smaller image within the larger image.

Now, I want to do this where the smaller image isn't a pixel-perfect version of the larger image.

For the new smaller image, the keypoints look like this:

[image]

You can see that in some cases, it matches correctly, and in some cases it doesn't.

If I call `findHomography` with these matches, it's going to take all of these data points into account and come up with a non-sensical warp perspective, because it's basing it on the correct matches and the incorrect matches.

[image]

What I'm looking for is a missing step in between detecting the good matches, and calling `findHomography`, where I can look at the relationship between the matches, and determine which matches are therefore correct.

I'm wondering if there's a function within OpenCV that I should be looking at for this step, or if this is something I'll need to work out on my own, and if so how I should go about doing that?

Comment: My first thought was RANSAC and looking to the [documentation of `findHomography`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) I found that it supports a RANSAC mode :) also a least-median one. Try using `cv2.RANSAC` as method

Comment: @api55 perfect, thanks! is there any way to determine whether the homography result is reasonable? for example, using it with RANSAC on that image might return a good result, but used on another image, or with a different ransacReprojThreshold or SURF hessianThreshold, it could return one similar the one shown above, rather than None.

Comment: well a homography is kind of a way of mapping one point to another one... if it is wrong it will have a totally different point right? then you can find how much it differs for your points and (you are already giving to the function the points and the ones you expect to have after the mapping) you get an estimate of how good it was... this is what the ReprojThrshold of RANSAC is suppose to do (with not all the points).... but you can re check with as many points you want

Comment: +1 to @api55's suggestion. Note that you can use `cv2.perspectiveTransform()` to transform just the point set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a blog in about finding object in scene last year( 2017.11.11). Maybe it helps. Here is the link. https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/30936804

Env: OpenCV 3.3 + Python 3.5

---

Found matches:

[image]

The found object in the scene:

[image]

---

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.11.11 01:44:37 CST
# 2017.11.12 00:09:14 CST
"""
使用Sift特征点检测和匹配查找场景中特定物体。
"""

import cv2
import numpy as np
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 4

imgname1 = "box.png"
imgname2 = "box_in_scene.png"

## (1) prepare data
img1 = cv2.imread(imgname1)
img2 = cv2.imread(imgname2)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


## (2) Create SIFT object
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

## (3) Create flann matcher
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(dict(algorithm = 1, trees = 5), {})

## (4) Detect keypoints and compute keypointer descriptors
kpts1, descs1 = sift.detectAndCompute(gray1,None)
kpts2, descs2 = sift.detectAndCompute(gray2,None)

## (5) knnMatch to get Top2
matches = matcher.knnMatch(descs1, descs2, 2)
# Sort by their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x[0].distance)

## (6) Ratio test, to get good matches.
good = [m1 for (m1, m2) in matches if m1.distance < 0.7 * m2.distance]

canvas = img2.copy()

## (7) find homography matrix
## 当有足够的健壮匹配点对（至少4个）时
if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    ## 从匹配中提取出对应点对
    ## (queryIndex for the small object, trainIndex for the scene )
    src_pts = np.float32([ kpts1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kpts2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    ## find homography matrix in cv2.RANSAC using good match points
    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
    ## 掩模，用作绘制计算单应性矩阵时用到的点对
    #matchesMask2 = mask.ravel().tolist()
    ## 计算图1的畸变，也就是在图2中的对应的位置。
    h,w = img1.shape[:2]
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
    ## 绘制边框
    cv2.polylines(canvas,[np.int32(dst)],True,(0,255,0),3, cv2.LINE_AA)
else:
    print( "Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))


## (8) drawMatches
matched = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kpts1,canvas,kpts2,good,None)#,**draw_params)

## (9) Crop the matched region from scene
h,w = img1.shape[:2]
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
perspectiveM = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(dst),pts)
found = cv2.warpPerspective(img2,perspectiveM,(w,h))

## (10) save and display
cv2.imwrite("matched.png", matched)
cv2.imwrite("found.png", found)
cv2.imshow("matched", matched);
cv2.imshow("found", found);
cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Best example implementation found so far!